How to Generate string of all combination starting from A to ZZZZZZZZ in bash
I want to start generating from a single length char and generate all possible values till (ZZZZZZZZZZ) 10-Zs.
I know I can do something like {A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}.... but I want to increment the length of character sequence in the outer loop.
Is there any way to implement this in bash? I tried the below script but the problem is that for loop command considers "{A..Z}" literally as a string.
#!/bin/bash

seq={A..Z}
cur_seq=""
for i in {0..10}; do
        cur_seq=${cur_seq}${seq}
        for a in $cur_seq; do
                echo $a
                ead kk
        done
done


When I look at this, the solution that looks obvious to me (other than not using bash for something as intrinsically slow as this is -- when you're doing expensive things you don't want a language runtime that's going to slow you down) is to write a recursive function that, given a line of input, writes first that exact line to output, then that line with each of {A..Z} appended. That way you're only ever evaluating one brace expansion at a time. Pipe printf '%s\n' {A..Z} into nine copies of that function, and there you are.

Even if your code worked in theory, in practice I don't think {A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z} would work: it asks Bash to hold more than a petabyte (a million gigabytes) of data in memory at once.

does the output need to be in any particular order (eg, all 1-char strings (sorted), then all 2-char strings (sorted), then all 3-char strings (sorted)) or does order not matter as long as all possible strings are generated?

@ruakh Absolutely. To be accurate, if 10-character strings are stored on 11 bytes, that would be 11*26^10 bytes (1552838052187136, about 1.55 peta-bytes). If we add the 1-character to 9-characters strings all this amounts to 1609079023095439 (about 1.6 peta-bytes).

Bash is a very poor choice of languages for this purpose -- I'm going to assume it's an academic exercise.
One way to implement this that works around the memory limitations that would break any attempt to generate a brace expansion of the length exposed would look like:
maybe_append() {
  local recurse_count arg line # declare locals so they don't leak
  recurse_count=$1; shift      # pop fixed arguments off our arg list
                               # ...everything we don't shift off will be in $@
  while IFS= read -r line; do : line="$line"
    printf '%s_\n' "$line"     # flag first output as needing no further suffix
    [[ $line = *_ ]] && continue      # input with an _ == skip
    for arg in "$@"; do : arg="$arg"  # everything past here goes into the...
      printf '%s%s\n' "$line" "$arg"  # ...recursive pipeline.
    done
  done | {
    if (( recurse_count > 1 )); then
      # pass output into another copy of this function to append more
      maybe_append "$((recurse_count - 1))" "$@"
    else
      tr -d '_' # done recursing: don't add anything else, just strip '_'s
    fi
  }
}

Given that, a demo using smaller/saner numbers looks like:
$ printf '%s\n' {A..C} | maybe_append 2 {A..C}
A
AA
AAA
AAB
AAC
AB
ABA
ABB
ABC
AC
ACA
ACB
ACC
B
BA

...etc; replace {A..C} and 2 to taste to make the logic work with larger ranges.

One of the important things about this approach is that we're never trying to store our result list in memory -- each instance of maybe_append (of which there's up to our desired string length minus one) stores at any given time the line of input it's transforming, its recursion depth, and the list of characters it can append; it's split off into separate processes (again, one per digit, so 10 in your example), but thanks to UNIX using copy-on-write following a fork(), most of the memory is shared between them.

I changed 2 to 4 and ran a few times; two issues ... a) it doesn't output the desired sequential series and b) repeated runs generate different output; for example, 2 sets of output for the CBA - CBC series: CBA AAAA CBB AAAB CBC vs CBA CBB AAAA CBC (out of order, not the same); if I then change from {A..C} to {A..Z} these issues occur throughout the output (eg, BP AAAYA AAAYB AAAYC AAAYD ABL AAAYE; I sorted the 4 / {A..Z} output (and diff'd against the sorted sets of other answers) and all strings are there

@markp-fuso, right, order isn't well-defined because of the file descriptor being split, but is that actually a problem? I didn't see any ordering requirement in the spec.

@markp-fuso, ...to be clear, the OP asks for code to start with A, not to start with AAAAAAAAAA, so I read the output of truncated values as a deliberate portion of the spec.

I guess it depends on how you read A to ZZZZZZZZZZ - all 1-char strings(sorted), followed by all 2-char strings(sorted), followed by all 3-char strings(sorted), etc? using 2 / {A..C} it looks like it's 'ordered' but that appears to be an issue of the series being too small for the race condition to occur

@markp-fuso, ...well -- regardless, it's easy enough to fix the ordering if we pass content through to the end of the pipeline; say, append a space, an =, or another distinct character on the end to mark something "done", and then have later pipeline phases recognize content and pass it through without further iteration when that sigil is present (until the very last pipeline phase, stripping the sigil there).

@markp-fuso, ...amended as described in the comment above; ordering now should be consistent between invocations.

on the + side, this bash script is about 4 times faster than my bash script; 'course if the order doesn't matter then further speedups could be had by breaking the problem into chunks that are run in parallel :-)

nod. I'd expect from a code read that this one would be slower to start (gotta fork the subprocesses) but faster once it's running (not constantly setting up and tearing down stack frames, and you've got separate processes handling different stages in the pipeline). OTOH, the reads are a bit of a wildcard; I could see there being an alternate universe where they make this one slower.

Using brace expansions for this exercise is problematic for a few reasons:

it's not easy to parameterize brace expansions
the final expansion works out to 26^10 (141,167,095,653,376) entries which ...
will likely consume a LOT more memory than your machine has available and ...
bash will need to first build that list of entries which means 100% cpu utilization for several days? weeks? months?

I propose replacing the brace expansion with an array to hold the list of letters, eg:
letters=( {A..Z} )

Assumption:

the output is to be sorted:
all 1-char strings (sorted), then ...
all 2-char strings (sorted), then ...
...
all 10-char strings (sorted)

One idea using a bash recursive function:
generate() {

    local curr_level in_string letter
    curr_level=${1:-1}
    in_string="$2"

    [[ "${curr_level}" -eq 0 ]] && { echo "${in_string}"; return; }

    for letter in "${letters[@]}"
    do
        generate $(( curr_level - 1 )) "${in_string}${letter}"
    done
}

The top level script then looks like:
letters=( {A..Z} )
max_level=10

for ((level=1; level<=max_level; level++))
do
    generate "${level}"
done

Taking for a test drive with a reduced data set (letters=( {A..C} ); max_level=2):
A
B
C
AA
AB
AC
BA
BB
BC
CA
CB
CC


As already pointed out in comments, doing this type of operation in bash is going to be (excruciatingly) slow, especially as you increase the number of characters (aka max_level).
Any number of tools (eg, perl, python, ruby, awk, etc) are going to be much faster.
One awk approach that implements the same logic as the (above) bash script:
awk -v max_level="${max_level}" '

function generate(curr_level, in_string,    i) {

    if (curr_level == 0) {
       print in_string
       return
    }

    for (i=1; i <= letter_count; i++)
        generate( curr_level-1, in_string letters[i] )
}

    { letters[++letter_count] = $1 }                       # store (bash array) letters in awk array letters[]

END { for (level=1; level <= max_level; level++)
          generate( level, "" )
    }

' <(printf "%s\n" "${letters[@]}")                        # feed bash array letters[] to awk in the form of a single letter per line

Taking for a test drive with the same reduced data set (letters=( {A..C} ); max_level=2):
A
B
C
AA
AB
AC
BA
BB
BC
CA
CB
CC


Here are the timings for running the bash and awk scripts with an expanded data set (letters=( {A..Z} ); max_level=5):
$ time bash_script

real    2m31.604s
user    2m23.357s
sys     0m8.192s


$ time awk_script

real    0m2.511s
user    0m2.447s
sys     0m0.052s

For 26 letters and max_level=5 we see the awk script is ~60 times faster than the bash script. This difference will increase significantly as you increase the max_level.

Might consider (( curr_level == 0 )) -- if writing bash-only code, might as well take advantages of extensions that improve clarity.

Yes, we can do this in Bash.  For example, here's a recursive method that generates these strings:
#!/usr/bin/bash

set -eu

declare -ar suffix=('' {A..Z})

letter_seq() {
    local letter digits=$1 prefix="${2-}"
    if ((digits))
    then
        for letter in "${suffix[@]:0${prefix:+1}}"
        do letter_seq $((digits-1)) "$prefix$letter"
        done
    elif [ "$prefix" ]
    then
        echo "$prefix"
    fi
}
 
letter_seq 10

We only brace-expand the initial list, which we use to populate the read-only array.
The tricky expansion of ${suffix[@]:0${prefix:+1}} is to eliminate the empty string from the loop when $prefix is non-empty; the rest of the code should be reasonably self-evident.

However, this kind of manipulation is slow in shell.  Much faster to write and compile a simple C program:
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIGITS 10

int main(void)
{
    char buf[DIGITS+2] = { '\0' };

    char const *begin = buf+DIGITS;
    for (;;) {
        /* increment number */
        char *p = buf + DIGITS + 1;
        while ((*--p)++ == 'Z') {
            *p = 'A';
        }
        if (*p == 1) {
            /* prepending another digit */
            if (p == buf) {
                /* finished */
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }
            begin = p;
            *p = 'A';
        }
        /* print it */
        puts(begin);
    }
}

I tried running the shell version with a 4-character limit, and it took more than 12 seconds of user-space CPU time on my machine, whereas the C program was too quick to measure (less than 10 milliseconds).
Increasing the output to 6 characters (i.e. 676 times as much work) pushed the C program up to 5.7 seconds; that's well over 1000 times as fast as the shell function.

If necessary, you could embed the C program into your shell script thus:
#!/bin/sh

set -eu

file=$(mktemp)

gcc -o "$file" -Wall -Wextra -x c - <<EOF
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define DIGITS 10

int main(void)
{
    char buf[DIGITS+2] = { '\0' };

    char const *begin = buf+DIGITS;
    for (;;) {
        /* increment number */
        char *p = buf + DIGITS + 1;
        while ((*--p)++ == 'Z') {
            *p = 'A';
        }
        if (*p == 1) {
            /* prepending another digit */
            if (p == buf) {
                /* finished */
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }
            begin = p;
            *p = 'A';
        }
        puts(begin);
    }
}
EOF

exec "$file"


Perhaps python offers a better alternative, and you can do something like this
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_uppercase
from functools import partial

f = partial(product, ascii_uppercase)
n = range(1, 11) 
for s in ("".join(r) for p in map(lambda r: f(repeat=r), n) for r in p): 
    print(s)


The downvote isn't mine, and this does what the OP is asking for; but quite frankly, if they don't know python this isn't really good enough w/o a LOT of explanatory words. I guess the downvoter thought that code-only answers are useless?

Not just that, but (while it's not my downvote either) this is simply nonresponsive; question asked for an answer "in bash". What are we going to do next, start answering Java questions with C answers because it's possible to run C programs from Java? At least show how to embed the Python script inside a shell script -- python3 -c ' at the top and a closing single quote at the bottom would be making at least a gesture towards trying to follow the bounds of the question as asked.

We can consider your problem as counting in base 26 using only A-Z digits. We count 1 digit numbers first (0 to 25), then 2 digits (0 to 26^2 - 1), etc. The to_string n m function converts n (the number passed as its first argument) to base 26 with digits A-Z on m digits.
If you can wait a few centuries (approximately 5 according my experiments on a quad core Intel Core i7 at 3.6 GHz):
declare -a a=( {A..Z} )
to_string() {
  local -i n=$1 m=$2
  local s
  for (( m; m > 0; m-- )); do
    s=${a[n % 26]}$s
    (( n /= 26 ))
  done
  printf '%s\n' $s
}

for (( i = 1; i <= 10; i++ )); do
  for (( n = 0; n < 26**i; n++ )); do
    to_string $n $i
  done
done


Not quite 5.7 seconds for 6-char combos, but I did get awk to crank them out in 8.17 secs, which is really quite decent for non-compiled non-JIT interpreted scripting code -

Instead of recursion or memoization/caching, it performs string squaring instead - it's exactly like binary squaring, performed over strings and chars instead of numbers. Binary doubling is relatively inadequate.

As long as the input string is pre-sorted, then all generated combos are also pre-sorted. Ideally it should act differently according to the odd/even bits for the input value. For now, it's simply a few hard-coded speed ups for powers of 2.

5-char combos got benchmarked at 0.327 secs

  for __ in $( jot 15 -3 ) ; do ( time ( echo "$__" | 

   mawk2 '

   function ________(__, _, ___, ____, _____, ______) {

       if ((__ = int(__)) < !__)
           return

       else if (__ == index(___ = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", _ = "")) { 
           
           gsub(/./, ",&", ___)
           return substr(___, ++_+_) 

       } else if ((_ += ++_)^((_+_+_)^_-_) < length(___)^__)
           return ERRNO = "ERR_OUPUT_OVER_34_BITS"

       gsub(".", "\\&&", ___)
       ______ = "&[^&]+"

       if (__ == _ || __ == _+_ || __ == _*_*_ || __ == _^_^_) {

           do gsub(______, ___,
                           ___)
           while (_ <= (__/=_)) 
       
       } else if (__ == _+_+_) {

           ____ = ___
           gsub(______, ____, ___)
           gsub(______, ____, ___)
           gsub(______,  ___, ___)
       
       } else {
          ____ = ___
          while (--__)
              gsub(______,____,___) 
       }

       gsub(/&/, ",", ___)
       return length(___) 
   } 
   ($++NF = ________($_))' ) | pv ) | gcat -b; echo "\f\t$__ done ...."; done  


 out9: 0.00  B 0:00:00 [0.00  B/s] [0.00  B/s] [<=> ]
 ( echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.01s system 83% cpu 0.008 total

-3 done ....

 out9: 0.00  B 0:00:00 [0.00  B/s] [0.00  B/s] [<=> ]
 ( echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 65% cpu 0.004 total

-2 done ....

 out9: 0.00  B 0:00:00 [0.00  B/s] [0.00  B/s] [<=> ]
 ( echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 68% cpu 0.004 total

-1 done ....

 out9: 0.00  B 0:00:00 [0.00  B/s] [0.00  B/s] [<=> ]
 ( echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 74% cpu 0.003 total

0 done ....

 out9: 54.0  B 0:00:00 [ 399KiB/s] [ 399KiB/s] [<=> ]
 ( echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 71% cpu 0.004 total
 1  1 A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z


1 done ....

 out9: 7.00  B 0:00:00 [81.4KiB/s] [81.4KiB/s] [<=>]
 ( echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 78% cpu 0.003 total
 1  2 2028


2 done ....

 out9: 8.00  B 0:00:00 [97.7KiB/s] [97.7KiB/s] [<=> ]
 ( echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.00s user 0.00s system 70% cpu 0.004 total
 1  3 70304


3 done ....

 out9: 10.0  B 0:00:00 [ 112KiB/s] [ 112KiB/s] [<=> ]
 ( echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.01s user 0.00s system 94% cpu 0.015 total
 1  4 2284880


4 done ....

 out9: 11.0  B 0:00:00 [36.1  B/s] [36.1  B/s] [<=> ]
 ( echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  0.29s user 0.04s system 99% cpu 0.327 total
 1  5 71288256


5 done ....

 out9: 13.0  B 0:00:08 [1.60  B/s] [1.60  B/s] [<=> ]
 ( echo "$__" | mawk2 ; )  7.25s user 0.92s system 99% cpu 8.171 total
 1  6 2162410432


6 done ....

